# VBA: Mirror a cell to another sheet, then keep the data after deleting the original

Tags: vba, excel

Apologies if this has been answered, but I couldn't find any details of this being asked before. I know it's a vague question without code, but just looking for ideas of how to approach this. Writing VBA code on Excel.

I have a sheet, which contains 20+ columns and 8,000+ rows of data. The sheet is password protected / read only as I do not want users editing the data (the sheet is linked to several other macros). Called 'Master Data Sheet'.

I have created a macro that will filter the Master Data table and then paste the filtered results on another sheet (called 'Filtered Results') and combines data with another separate sheet. The user can view and edit this sheet.

**However there are two columns that I want the user to put data in that needs to be duplicated/mirrored in the Master Data Sheet (in those specific columns) automatically. Issue I'm having is that the 'Filtered Results' sheet gets deleted after a period of time, but I still need the user input data for those specific columns to be in the Master Data Sheet.**

I'm unsure how to get around the issue of the sheet being deleted but data being retained.

An alternative workaround I had would be a copy/paste button the user could click to copy the unformatted data from the Filtered Sheet to Master Data Sheet. However, I was hoping to find a solution that would just automatically update as the user types (in case they forget to click the button etc.)

Thanks for all the help!

EDIT: Code I'm working with right now. Still stuck on linking filtered cells though.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

  Application.EnableEvents=False

    If Not Intersect (Target, Range("D1:D1000")) Is Nothing Then
          Target.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Master Data 
          File").Range(Target.Address)
    End If

  Application.EnableEvents=True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Worksheet_Change` event to check if a specific range changed and then copy/update the other sheet. This way you have the copy/paste automatically when the original data changed.

Example:
If you want to copy range A1:A5 into another sheet whenever its values changed:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A5")) Is Nothing Then 'range A1:A5 was changed
        Target.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("OtherSheet").Range(Target.Address)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks PEH. I get this to almost work, but when it 'copies' the cell across, it goes into the Master Data Sheet (MDS) in the same cell. i.e. Mirroring cell A5 in the Filtered Sheet (FS) results changes cell A5 in the MDS.

However, in the FS, the data has been filtered, so the cells don't match those in the MDS. i.e. cell A5 in FS is cell A19 in the MDS, but the matched value will still display in A5 regardless. 

Any ideas how to get around this? Have posted the code I'm currently using in the OP.

Comment: Further to this, I'm not sure how to add a new sheet (the Filtered Data Sheet) with this Worksheet Change code already embedded. Had a look at the Visual Basic Extensibility but struggling to understand it.